# Insert Fullscreen PDF rotated 90°

Tags: pdf, rotating, landscape, fullpage

I have a PDF in landscape and would like to add it to my thesis just as it is in the picture below.

It needs to be on the fullpage and I would like to add the caption directly in the middle over the pdf as shown below. Its in german and reads "Abbildung 4.6: Schaltplan"

I tried a lot but can't figure it out.

1. Which package do I need to use?
2. And how do I insert it fullframe?
3. How to rotate it?
4. How to overlay the caption?

Would be awesome if someone managed to help me!

[image: Exactly how I want to add my PDF file]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem.
just rotate the PDF on the pc and then this post should help you:

[Formatting figure captions overlayed with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284686/formatting-figure-captions-overlayed-with-tikz)

Comment: If you have the PDF tools, it sounds like the easiest solution. But it does not solve the caption problem, right?

Comment: In the link I provided the problem is solved. Insert PDF with TikZ and then you can overlay the caption. 
Just look at the answer of the post I have linked too!
To rotate a PDF use adobe reader 
1- Rotate the PDF 
2 -print it using microsoft print to pdf, make sure to select portrait or landscape, if the setting is set to auto it will not rotate it!!!!